# SQL query joining tables from different fdb databases

Tags: sql, firebird, join, firebird2.1

I have 2 fdb databases `company.fdb` and `timeAtt.fdb`

`company.fdb` contains `staffDetail` table

```
staffId       - 001
staffName     - Andy
staffStatus   - Active
```

`timeAtt.fdb`contains `staffAtt` table

```
staffId         - 001
staffName       - Andy
timeIn          - 07:30
timeOut         - 04:30
LI              - X (late in)
AB              - X (absent )
remarks         - Emergency leave
```

Now, i would like to view the staff who was absent only which i did it this way

```
SELECT staffId,staffName,remarks FROM timeAtt.fdb WHERE AB = 'X'
```

But the problem is, the query also display inactive staff. So i need to join `staffAtt` from `timeAtt.fdb` and `staffDetail` from `company.fdb` to display only staff with active status. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. In Firebird you can only join tables in the same database file. Firebird 2.5 expanded [`EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt) to also execute a statement on an external datasource, but having a single query reference tables in different databases is not possible.

You have the following options:

1. Create a temporary table, copy the data you need into that temporary table and then join to the temporary table,
2. Merge the database into one.

Comment: I see... i cant do this in firebird... Im gonna try the temp table method. Tq Mark

Answer (score 9):

As Mark notes, you cannot join them directly. But you can still use a DSQL statement to get what you want.

Use `execute block` and `execute statement` together. Here's an example:

```
execute block
returns (
   staffId integer,
   staffName varchar(100),
   remarks varchar(100)
   staffStatus varchar(10))
as
begin
   for SELECT staffId, staffName, remarks 
   FROM timeAtt 
   WHERE AB = 'X'
   into :staffId, :staffName, :remarks do begin

      execute statement 'select staffStatus from company where staffId = ' || staffId
      on external "your:connection:\string\and\db.fdb" as user FOO password BAR
      into :staffStatus;

      suspend;
   end
end
```